# Search for string with umlauts seems to not work with Spring JPA ES

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an object which is stored to embedded ES instance:

```
@Document(indexName = "users", type = "user")
public class Uer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String uid;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, store = true, includeInParent = true)
    private LanguageValue name;

    @Data
    public static class LanguageValue {

        private String eng;

        private String deu;
    }
}
```

For search by name I use `List<User> findByNameDeuContaining(String name);` and passing a value wraped by wildcards. For names without umlauts it works fine, but any name containing an umlaut I get no results..

Bug or misconfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

Try @Field annotation with *analyzer* parameter:

```
@Document(indexName = "lang")
public class Test {

    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.no, store = false)
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private LanguageValue namecustom;

}

class LanguageValue {

    @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.analyzed, analyzer = "standard", searchAnalyzer = "standard")
    private String en;

    @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.analyzed, analyzer = "de_std", searchAnalyzer = "de_std")
    private String de;
}
```

This gives following mapping:

```
{
    "lang": {
        "mappings": {
            "test": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "namecustom": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "de": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "de_std"
                            },
                            "en": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "standard"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```